# Flexbox item (hide and show) modify the alignment of my previous items, what can i do?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with display:flex, and i have 4 items inside but the last item is a span which is displayed only after pressing a button and this span started with display:none.
The items are centered in the div vertically and horizontally.
When i press the button, the span appear but change the position of previous elements.

[This is the image of first 3 elements centered in the right way with span display:none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrmvn.png)

[This is the image of first 4 elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zOVT.png)

As you can see, the first three elements, when appear the span, they are shifted up and to the left.

I want to keep static the position of the first 3 elements when span appear.
I want the first three elements centered like the first image, and span appear below the third element but without shift the other elements.

What can i do? Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
<div id="buy">
    <p>Prezzo: 39,10 €</p>
    <div id="quantityDiv"></div>
    <button id="button0">Aggiungi al carrello</button>
    <span id="messageAdd0"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#buy {
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

#buy > * {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#buy span {
    background: #24252A;
    display: none;
}
```

JS just use hide() and show() for the span when button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot use `justify-self: end;` on that specific element without not affecting the positions of the other flex child elements -
the best you can do so far (unless a better idea emerges) is to use `position:absolute` on that element with `top:100%` inside a `position:relative` parent:

```css
.product {
  display: flex;
}

.buy {
  position: relative; /* Add this one */
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.buy > * {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.buy > .messageAdd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <h1>Prodotto 1</h1>
  <div class="buy">
    <p>Prezzo: 39,10 €</p>
    <div class="quantityDiv"></div>
    <button class="button" disabled>Aggiungi al carrello</button>
    <span class="messageAdd">È stato raggiunto il limite di 5 biglietti!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, don't use IDs instead of classes. Use classes. ID should be unique!
Also, SEO-wise, don't use more than one `h1`-per-document.

## Modify your HTML!

You could instead modify your HTML markup, by introducing a parent for the product specification:

```css
.product {
  display: flex;
}
.buy {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.buy-specs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.buy > * {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.buy-message {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <h1>Prodotto 1</h1>
  <div class="buy">
    <div class="buy-specs">
      <p class="buy-specs-price">Prezzo: 39,10 €</p>
      <div class="buy-specs-quantity"></div>
      <button class="buy-specs-add button" disabled>Aggiungi al carrello</button>
    </div>
    <span class="buy-message">È stato raggiunto il limite di 5 biglietti!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tryed but the effect is the same.
Thank you for the advice, by the way.

Comment: @BlowLore added another example that requires a change in your HTML markup

Comment: Yes! Now it's working. Last thing, i wanted the div 'buy' centered vertically in the div 'product'. I tryed with justify-content: center, but when span appear shift up a little bit the div 'buy-specs', but i don't want the div to move. There is a way to do this?

Comment: @BlowLore could you share a picture of what you're after? You mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ncdh3ay0/

Answer (score 0):

make another div for the span element that you want to hide and show after the click event and then set its position to absolute which will not allow the item to change the other elements position when appearing.

Comment: Seems to work, but when i press the button the span appear in the center and not below the button, i dont know why because the div inside the div flexbox

Comment: after setting the positions of the span element to absolute you can also set its position by left, right, top and bottom this will not disturb the other div element because the position is set to absolute. I recommend you to watch some videos about positioning elements because even for me that was the hardest part to understand, Here is the link to the video that I watched  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jx5jmI0UlXU&t=491s)

Answer (score 0):

you could solve this by simply wrapping the span with div and then give  suitable width and height for the div